# meteor deploying with 0.6.5

Tags: meteor

After I updated my Meteor app to 0.6.5 using

```
meteor update
```

and deployed it to my shared server (webfaction). I have a new error that appeared without me changing the application  :

```
/home/me/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:184
}).run();
   ^
Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash
    at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)
    at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)
    at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1029)
    at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)
    at packages/livedata.js:3907:4
    at packages/livedata.js:3918:3
    at /home/me/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:153:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/me/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/me/webapps/meteor/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
```

Downgrading to 0.6.4.1 fixes the issue.

I would very much like to understand why the error is coming with 0.6.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your ROOT_URL. Make sure it starts with http://

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with changes to the package API in 0.6.5. See the release notes - http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/14/meteor-065-namespacing-modularity-new-build-system-source-maps

And this meteor-talk thread - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-talk/BbrjGcGGIzc/discussion